# Cognito Form disabled due to suspicious content

Tags: cognito-forms

This appears:

> Our apologies, this form has been disabled due to suspicious content. If you believe you have received this message in error, please contact the original form author.

How can I make my form code work?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. Normally this message is shown to a user when their form is trying to collect personal information or credentials that could be used in malicious ways. We have reviewed your form and it meets our safety criteria, so now we’re looking into why our filters still disabled your form. I see that you submitted a support ticket as well, so we’ll continue to work with you through that to get your form up and running again. We apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I'm asked to send a 50$ apple gift card to be able to post on my site. Www.knoweretetorun.com they say they go into the server which is only acceded by customers by an encrypted I'd only purchased by your email I'd to prevent data theft and recover your account